# What is the q-analogue of the Lefschetz decomposition?

Tags: quantum-groups

The representation theory behind the Lefschetz decomposition in Kahler geometry was summarised very neatly by Victor Protsak in his answer to
[29907](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29907)

Let $W$ be a $2n$-dimensional symplectic vector space, $\bigwedge^\ast W$ its exterior algebra, and $\omega\in\bigwedge^2 W$ the invariant two-form. Exterior multiplication by $\omega$ and the contraction with $\omega$  define a pair of $Sp(W)$-equivariant graded linear transformations $L, \Lambda$ of $\bigwedge^\ast W$ into itself of degrees $2$ and $-2,$ and let $H=\deg-n$ be the graded degree $0$ map acting on $\bigwedge^k$ as multiplication by $k-n.$ Then $L,H,\Lambda$ form the standard basis of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl_2}$ acting on $\bigwedge^\ast W$ and the actions of $Sp(W)$ and $\mathfrak{sl_2}$ are the commutants of each other.

The representation theory is discussed in
[Remarks on classical invariant theory](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2001418?origin=crossref) by Roger Howe. This is also discussed in Griffiths and Harris "Principles of algebraic geometry" in Chapter 0, Section 7.

My question is whether anyone knows the $q$-analogue of the representation theory (and just to be clear I mean explicitly and not in principle). More specifically, we have an inclusion of $U_q(A_{n-1})$ in $U_q(C_n)$ by ignoring the end node. The vector representation restricts to $U\oplus U^*$ where $U$ is also the vector representation.
Then I want to define a $q$-analogue of the exterior algebra; ideally so it is a $U_q(C_n)$-module algebra. Then I want to construct the commutant, which ideally would be (a quotient of) $U_q(A_1)$.

I hope that by now there is a consensus of the definition of $U_q$.

Comment: I am not sure why you need to invoke type $A$ - it's purely symplectic question: skew duality between symplectic groups in Clifford representation. There was some work on $q$-analogues of the "usual" (symmetric) Howe duality by Japanese mathematicians, I don't have the references at the moment; it may have involved "non-consensus" def of $U_q$, though.

Comment: @Victor. Yes, I agree. I was thinking that I should take $\Lambda(U)\otimes \Lambda(U^*)$ (with $q$) and extend the action of $U_q(A_{n-1})$ to $U_q(C_n)$.